# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.. in google short url

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 public string GetShortURL(string longUrl)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=My_API_Key");
        request.Method = "POST";           
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        string requestData = string.Format(@"{{""longUrl"": ""{0}""}}", longUrl);
        byte[] requestRawData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestData);
        request.ContentLength = requestRawData.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestRawData, 0, requestRawData.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        return responseData;
    }
```

I am trying to create short url by passing my original url string but it is giving an exception

[image]

Comment: What key did you put in `My_API_Key`? Server key? Which domain?

Comment: Delete the above comment! I was asking which key type and which domain - do not write your key

Comment: 403 means forbidden, so check your credentials and setup information - did you place any restrrictions on usage of the key (e.g.  http referrers, ip addresses) in the google developer console? If so, check you're complying with those

Comment: No i am not placing any restrictions. @ADyson

Comment: How can we know the key type and domain @KobyDouek

Comment: @SrinivasCh Go to the Google API console and see which keys you have. I suggest you copy some screenshots and add them to your question. I had this issue too and I resloved it by verifying my key in the console.

Comment: I added Image please have a look.

Comment: Is that a server key? Please add more screenshots of the console so I can see which key is this and what is the allowed domains